# How do I refresh an html element?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I've tried searching for any possible solutions to my question but none of what I've seen so far works. Anyway, I'm using MVC 3 and I have a form called Add Event. On that page, I have a dropdownlist that contains a list of locations that the user can choose from. I have a link just below that dropdownlist that would allow a user to add a new location. Now, I have the textboxes, dropdowns, etc for creating a new location in a partial view which would appear below the dropdownlist when I click on the link.

Anyway, I need to refresh, just the dropdownlist so that when I add a new Location, it goes right on the list. What happens right now is after I click on save, the partial view hides itself and I still need to refresh the entire page to get the new location on the dropdown list which would then, remove everything I typed in on texboxes and dropdownlists on the same page.

How can I do this using javascript/ajax?

Comment: if i get you right i think you just need to move the data of the new location from the partial view to the dropdownlist by adding a new option using javascript helping you do that give me some of your code to be more aware

Comment: You might want to add ASP.NET tag to your question.

Comment: in the success function of the ajax call i think you have to add the new location to the dropdownlist with javascript like what amesh did down there with data you should return from the ajax call i think u need to return the location name to be setted to the text property and the id of the location to be setted to the value property of the new option :) that said if u need more details just say it :)

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LocationId, Model.LocationSelectList)
<a id="styleLocation">Add Location</a>
<div id="locationAdd">@Html.Partial("AddNewLocation")</div>          Here's my javascript when I add a location on the partial view      function saveLocation() {     var value = {
 location_City: $('#newCity').val();
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 traditional: true,
 url: "/Event/jsonAdd/",
 dataType: "json",
 data: value,
 success: function (result) {}
        });

Comment: Sorry, I can't seem to format the codes properly here. By the way, I use a javascript on the main form to call the partial view, then I use javascript to save new locations on the partial view and hide the partial view.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you..

```
var opt = document.createElement("option");
     // Assign text and value to Option object
    opt.text = Text;
    opt.value = Value;        

    // Add an Option object to Drop Down
    document.getElementById("YourDropDownID").options.add(opt,null);
```

Comment: Sorry, since I basically have two different views (the main form and the partial view) and both use ajax/javascript, do I add the codes on the partial view?

Comment: you can use this code either in the view or in the partial view. that doesn't matter  as finally both are meeting in the browser.

Comment: Okay, so I'm not sure if I've got the right values but this is what I've tried so far on the javascript but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    traditional: true,
    url: "/Service/jsonEdit/",
    dataType: "json",
    data: propertyValue,
    success: function (result) {
                        document.getElementById('hideAddProperty').style.display = "none";
                    var opt = document.createElement("option");
                    opt.text = propertyValue;
                    opt.value = propertyValue;
                    document.getElementById('#propertyReload').options.add(opt, null);

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can reload only the element you want:

$('#menu').load("myServerScript.php #menu");

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

this can be done with jQuery.
My way of doing it would be like this. Assuming that you have a form that looks something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    <select id="myList" name="myList">
        <option value="1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="newValue" name="newValue" />
    <a href="#" id="btn">add new value</a>            
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Where myList is dropdown you want to add a new value and refresh, newValue is the text field to receive the new values to be added to the dropdown (myList) and the link with id btn is the add button. You can add a jQuery that would look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.post("/home/addvalue", { value: $("#newValue").val() }, function (result) {
                if (result != null) {
                    $("#myList").append("<option value='" + result.id + "' selected='selected'>" + result.text + "</option>");
                }
            });
        });
    });
 </script>
```

What I'm is when you click on the link (btn) I collect the value (and just that value) from the text box and do POST (a form submit) to the server. 
I'm guessing you're expecting the server to give some sort of answer that includes the newly inserted value's id.
If the server sends back that new id, I then append the the new result to list (and set it as the selected one)

On the server side you code could look something like this

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddValue(FormCollection collection) 
{ 
    //do database inser for the new value and get the id
    var response = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    response.Add("id", 3);//3 here represents that last id
    response.Add("text", collection["value"]); //the value you sent for the new option
    return Json(response);
}
```

you receive the the POST(ed) data and do save to the database. Once the value is saved and you have the new id save in into a dictionary that you'll then serialize and send back as json the javascript above.
This would update your form, so you when you actually hit submit myList value would be the new value. 
Hope this helps (and if does, please accept the answer)

Comment: Will this approach work on two different html pages? I basically have a view for adding the events and a partial view that adds the new location

Comment: As long as the all the DOM elements (the ones that are referenced in javascript) are all loaded and accessible by the script. It shouldn't really matter where the're coming from.